# Matching the criteria and return the result

Tags: python

I have a jason file like this:

```
{
   "Rank": 1259,
   "Title": "Ischemic Nerve Block to Improve Hand Function in Stroke Patients",
   "Status": "Completed",
   "Study Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Cerebrovascular Accident",
   "Interventions": "Procedure: Transient deafferentation",
   "Locations": "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS), Bethesda, Maryland, United States",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT00056706"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 1260,
   "Title": "Transcranial Direct Current Stimulation for Post-stroke Motor Recovery",
   "Status": "Recruiting",
   "Study Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Stroke, Ischemic|Motor Activity|Upper Extremity Paralysis",
   "Interventions": "Device: Sham|Device: Low dose tDCS|Device: High dose tDCS|Behavioral: mCIMT",
   "Locations": "University of Alabama, Birmingham, Alabama, United States|University of California Los Angeles, Los Angeles, California, United States|MedStar National Rehabilitation Hospital, Washington, District of Columbia, United States|Emory University, Atlanta, Georgia, United States|University of Kentucky, Lexington, Kentucky, United States|Barnes Jewish Hospital, Saint Louis, Missouri, United States|Burke Rehabilitation Institute, White Plains, New York, United States|University of Cincinnati, Cincinnati, Ohio, United States|Moss Rehabilitation Research Institute, Elkins Park, Pennsylvania, United States|Medical University of South Carolina, Charleston, South Carolina, United States|Texas Medical Center, Houston, Texas, United States",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT03826030"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 1261,
   "Title": "Transient Ischemic Attack (TIA) Triage and Evaluation of Stroke Risk",
   "Status": "Completed",
   "Study Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Cerebrovascular Accident",
   "Interventions": "",
   "Locations": "UC Davis Medical Center, Davis, California, United States|Stanford University School of Medicine, Stanford, California, United States|Michigan State University, Grand Rapids, Michigan, United States",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT01423201"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 1282,
   "Title": "Atrial Fibrillation as a Cause of Stroke and Intracranial Hemorrhage Study (The FibStroke Study)",
   "Status": "Unknown status",
   "Study Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Stroke|Transient Ischemic Attacks|Intracranial Hemorrhage|Atrial Fibrillation",
   "Interventions": "",
   "Locations": "Keski-Suomi Central Hospital, Jyväskylä, Finland|Kuopio University Hospital, Kuopio, Finland|Satakunta Central Hospital, Pori, Finland|Turku University Hospital, Turku, Finland",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT02146040"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 1287,
   "Title": "Magnetic Resonance Imaging to Investigate Silent Strokes During Neck and Skull Angioplasty",
   "Status": "Completed",
   "Study Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Brain Ischemia",
   "Interventions": "",
   "Locations": "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS), Bethesda, Maryland, United States",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT00015717"
 }
```

The task is that "Find which clinical trials are being conducted at NINDS Bethesda, Maryland, United States".

So, I first import this jason as data called clinical_trials_data

```
import json
import pandas as pd
# Load dataset
with open("./data/IschemicStroke_Clinical_Trials.json") as file:
    clinical_trials_data = json.load(file)
```

Second, because the some Location contains multiple locations and use delimiter "|" to separate them, so I use code to retrieve the each location and store in location_info:

```
target_location = "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS) Bethesda, Maryland, United States"
trials_with_location = pd.DataFrame(clinical_trials_data)[pd.DataFrame(clinical_trials_data)["Locations"].notnull()]
location_info = trials_with_location["Locations"].str.split("|")
```

from there, I do not write the rest code to achieve the conditional or filter like if target_location in location_info, then print Title which is the trial's name.

i tried this code:

```
# Check if target_location is in location_info
if any(target_location in locations for locations in location_info):
    # If true, print the titles of trials conducted at the target location
    for title in clinical_trials_data["Title"]:
        print(title)
else:
    print("No trials conducted at the target location.")
```

But it does not return any record even the location is in the location_info.

Can someone help to point how to do that task?

Thanks~!

Comment: If this is a one-time homework task, then you don't need to split the locations, and you don't need pandas.  Just do `'NINDS' in xxx['Locations']`.

Comment: If that is literally the contents of your JSON file then you'll get a JSONDecodeError when you try to load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas for this.  Just search the list of dicts from the JSON:

```
for rec in clinical_trial_data:
    if 'NINDS' in rec['Locations']:
       print(rec['Title'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for this case. But further question is that how to achieve the exact matching for this condition? for example, what if the 3 records has the similar Location information: "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS), Bethesda, Maryland, United States",  "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS), Bethesda, Utah, United States", and "National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke (NINDS), Los Angeles, California, United States", and we just want to match the first one which in Maryland, United States? Thanks~~!

Comment: If you have the exact string (and remember it must be the EXACT string), then just put it where I have `'NINDS'`.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, how can I save this outcome and write it in a file. If I can subset this by using some code like ninds_trial=clinical_trials_data [ 'NINDS' in Location], i can later store it using code:"with open(f"task.txt", "w") as result_file:  result_file.write("Clinical trials being conducted at NINDS Bethesda, Maryland, United States:\n")
    result_file.write(ninds_trials_str + "\n\n")". But now with this print outcome, how can I store that? Thanks for your help~~!

Comment: You don't really need to ask me that, do you?  `print(rec['title'], file=result_file)`

Comment: No, I do, I need to write multiple results into one file in another code. Not only this one. This is a part of result. My final .text result includes: with open(f"task.txt", "w") as result_file:
     result_file.write(status_distribution_str + "\n\n")
    result_file.write("Drug Trials:\n" + drug_trials_str + "\n\n")
    result_file.write("Device Trials:\n" + device_trials_str + "\n\n")
    result_file.write(proportion_single_vs_multi_str + "\n\n")
    result_file.write(ninds_trials_str + "\n\n"), I do not know how to fit in this .

Comment: I figured out. Thanks for your help~~!